# Java allow to access Kotlin's base variable through it's child, but not Kotlin, why?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class as below

```
open class KotlinBase {
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "testing"
    }
}
```

And a child of it as

```
class KotlinChild : KotlinBase()
```

When I try to access TAG from a Java class, I could either

```
public class JavaOther {
    String test1 = KotlinBase.TAG; // This is okay
    String test2 = KotlinChild.TAG; // This is okay
}
```

However, when accessing from Kotlin class, I can't access through the Child.

```
class KotlinOther {
    val test1 = KotlinChild.TAG  // Compile/Syntax error
    val test2 = KotlinBase.TAG   // This is okay
}
```

Why can't my Kotlin class access the inherited variable `TAG` through `KotlinChild`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's a design decision allowing you to avoid ambiguities.** - child classes can have their own `companion object`s with fields/methods having same names as those in the parent.

By restricting access to companions only through the actual class, problems with ambiguous field/method shadowing do not exist anymore.

Also, companion objects are not `static` members known from other languages. Although, the majority of use cases overlap.

Additionally, remember that

```
KotlinBase.TAG
```

is a shortcut for:

```
KotlinBase.Companion.TAG
```